# get vibrate() to work in browser without PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, vibration

Does anybody know how to get something like navigator.vibrate() to work directly in the browser on a website (without using PhoneGap and the webview)? None of the commands found on http://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/ seem to work and all I could find are references to these commands working using PhoneGap. I have tried this fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/robnyman/BrFvC/

```
but no joy! :-(
```

I am running 
Android 2.3, native browser, Firefox 10 and Maxthon 2.4.5 on an HTC Sensation XE.
Does anybody know of a browser that supports this method (already)?

Comment: PhoneGap is just a wrapping layer, download the source and steal what you need.

Comment: You can't.  That's the whole point of PhoneGap: to bridge the **gap** between what you can do from a pure web application and what you can do with a native application. Someday the device manufacturers may provide more APIs for JavaScript in web pages, but there's a lot of incentive for them not to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I will give ZeroPage's suggestion a go and let you know once I got some results, but Pointy makes a really good point (pun not intended) re PhoneGaps' actual purpsose and the problem with the manufacturers' feature support. Let's hope I can dig up sth. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Using Javascript:

```
navigator.vibrate(pattern);
```

example:

```
navigator.vibrate(250);
```

where 250 = 250 ms vibrate.

But - this is not fully supported across all browsers (Namely not by Safari).  Check Browser Support for Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=vibration

Comment: Chrome/Android (v.7 Nougat) won't vibrate when in sleep mode. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser, currently I've only found firefox mobile beta to support the vibrate API. You can find an [example showing how this works here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/html5-remotely-vibrate-phone-morse-code-using-web-sockets-and-vibrate-api).

Basically you just have to make the following call:

```
navigator.mozVibrate(toPlay);
```

Comment: cheers. yeah I have read that the lates FF now supports vibrate via their webAPI on ICS.
" As of the latest Nightly, Firefox 11 for Android can now read the battery state, capture images from the camera, send SMSes, and trigger the vibrator motor."

from: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/107211-mozillas-webapi-for-firefox-takes-shape-porn-sites-quiver-in-anticipation