# Where is the Vibration API hiding in Chrome 23?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, vibration

According to a [post](http://peter.sh/2012/08/key-bindings-for-extensions-and-media-streams-for-the-web-audio-api/) on Peter Beverloo's blog, "The webkit prefix has been dropped from the Vibration API implementation as it reached Candidate Recommendation."

In [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.vibrate), the Vibration API can be found at navigator.vibrate (per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-vibration-20120508/)), not so in Chrome 23 - with or without the webkit prefix.  I've tried enabling *experimental javascript* in chrome://flags but to no effect.

Despite playing around in devtools and plenty of searching on the net, I'm still unable to locate this API.  Where is it hiding?

Comment: look's like only firefox supports it for now. Similar question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266285/get-vibrate-to-work-in-browser-without-phonegap

Comment: So far as I can tell, Chromium [has yet to add support for it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114524), as the Issue is still open.

Comment: It's really laggy in Firefox currently. http://jsbin.com/ufomep/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog was just indicating that the API has been unprefixed in WebKit.  We don't have it in Chrome for Desktop and we don't have it in Chrome for Android as of version 25

Comment: Thanks Kinlan; I assumed that Chrome would've picked the change up.  My bad.