# HTML5 vibration API support

Tags: html, cross-browser, vibration

I checked on http://caniuse.com/ but can't find anything about compatibility for the vibration API.

Which browsers support it?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.vibrate) says that Firefox and Chrome support it.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work in Chrome 24 though

Comment: MDN says that Chrome supports a prefixed version, but yeah, I can't find such method in `navigator` (desktop version) too. You can use `var vib=navigator.vibrate || navigator.mozVibrate || navigator.webkitVibrate || function(){};` to hold a global method.

Comment: Not sure of the current status but the prefix was dropped in webkit changeset 124358: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/124358 - Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633561/where-is-the-vibration-api-hiding-in-chrome-23

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update [2014-03-07]**: The Vibration API is now supported by Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. I've also made this information available on on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=vibration).

---

Based on [this article](http://jspro.com/apis/the-buzz-about-the-vibration-api/):

> The Vibration API is still primarily unsupported. Firefox 16+ is
>   currently the only browser with support for the API.

Comment: The vibration API will also be supported in Chrome 30 for Android. http://blog.chromium.org/2013/08/chrome-30-beta-richer-web-on-android.html

Comment: Vibration API is available starting with Chrome 32 (http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/chrome-32-beta-animated-webp-images-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.vibrate) it is supported in Chrome with prefix webkit, in Firefox 11+ with prefix moz and in Firefox 16+ without any prefix.

But as you can check in this [Issue in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114524) as of now it is not supperted in Chrome and they seem to be in no hurry as Priority is 2(Normal).

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in Android strock browser as of now.

Comment: This should be comment not an answer.

Comment: This is an answer to the main question "Which browsers support it?" and not a fine tuning of the question.
Android stock browser is a different product from all Firefox, Chrome and Opera covered by the other 2 answers.
What else to comment???